# Modify function to filter by several data-attributes simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, custom-data-attribute

The function below allows users to filter products by `data-attributes`, and accommodates filtering by multiple values simultaneously. It does this by creating an array of the values selected, and when any of the values are clicked (in this case checked/unchecked) it hides all the items and then re-shows those that match the values in the updated array.

It works correctly when filtering for one `data-attribute`, but when combined to filter by more than one attribute it no longer shows all results matching any of the values and instead only shows results matching all the specified values.

I've posted a fiddle which demonstrates the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/94/ All but one of the items have the values of both `data-style="V-Neck"` and `data-color="Black"` and they should therefore remain visible if either of the filters are selected, but if another value from a different `data-attribute` some of the items are hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected = [];
    $('#attributes-Colors *').click(function () {
        var attrColor = $(this).data('color');
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(attrColor),1);
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected.push(attrColor);
        }
        $("#content").find("*").hide();
        $.each(selected, function(index,item) {
            $('#content').find('[data-color *="' + item + '"]').show();
        });
        return false;
    });

$('#attributes-Silhouettes *').click(function () {
        var attrStyle = $(this).data('style');
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(attrStyle),1);
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected.push(attrStyle);
        }           
        $("#content").find("*").hide();
        $.each(selected, function(index,item) {
            $('#content').find('[data-style *="' + item + '"]').show();
        });
       return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: There are 2 click handlers for `$('#attributes-Silhouettes *')` declared on line 24 and then line 25. Probably just a copy/paste issue and may not reflect your actual code. In any event, commenting one out seems to result in the same behavior as your earlier working example. http://jsfiddle.net/WZpMh/54/

Comment: @Bryan - At least I know why the function stopped working :-) Now that it's actually running I found the issue with the way it runs when combined - when filtering for more than one data-attribute it's no longer showing all results matching any of the values and instead only shows results matching all the specified values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your handlers are updating the `selected` array, but only one handler executes on a `click`. The first one if a color was (de)selected, the second if a style. Let's say you've clicked on "Black" and "Crew Neck". At that time your selected array would look like this: `[ "Black", "Crew_Neck" ]`. The next time you make a selection, let's say you click "Short Sleeves", the second (style) handler executes. Here's what is happening:

1. `Short_Sleeves`  gets added to the selected array.
2. All of the items are hidden using `$("#content").find("*").hide();`
3. The selected array is iterated and items are shown again based on a dynamic selector.

Number 3 is the problem. In the above example, a style was clicked so the style handler is executing. Any items in the selected array that are colors will fail because, for example, no elements will be found with a selector such as `$('#content').find('[data-style *="Black"]').show();`.

I would suggest 2 things.

1. Keep 2 arrays of selections, one for color, one for style.
2. Combine your code to use only a single handler for both groups.

Here's a (mostly) working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/WZpMh/98/).

Note that I added a `data-type="color|style"` to your `.filterOptions` containers to allow for combining to use a single handler and still know which group was changed.

Here's the full script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // use 2 arrays so the combined handler uses correct group 
    var selected = { color: [], style: [] };

    // code was similar enough to combine to 1 handler for both groups
    $('.filterOptions').on("click", "a", function (e) {
        // figure out which group...
        var type = $(e.delegateTarget).data("type");
        var $this = $(this);
        // ...and the value of the checkbox checked
        var attrValue = $this.data(type);

        // same as before but using 'type' to access the correct array
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $this.parent().removeClass("active");
            selected[type].splice(selected[type].indexOf(attrValue),1);
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().addClass("active");
            selected[type].push(attrValue);
        }

        // also showing all again if no more boxes are checked
        if (attrValue == 'All' || $(".active", ".filterOptions").length == 0) {
            $('#content').find('*').show();
        } 
        else {
            // hide 'em all
            $("#content").find("*").hide();
            // go through both style and color arrays
            for (var key in selected) {
                // and show any that have been checked
                $.each(selected[key], function(index,item) {
                    $('#content').find('[data-' + key + ' *="' + item + '"]').show();
                });
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

**UPDATE: incorporating suggestions from comments**

To make the handler work with checkboxes instead of links was a small change to the event binding code. It now uses the `change` method instead of `click` and listens for `:checkbox` elements instead of `a`:

```
$('.filterOptions').on("change", ":checkbox", function (e) {
    // handler code
});
```

The "All" options "hiccup" was a little harder to fix than I thought it would be. Here's what I ended up with:

```
// get a jQuery object with all the options the user selected
var checked = $(":checked", ".filterOptions");

// show all of the available options if...
if (checked.length == 0 // ...no boxes are checked
    || // ...or...
    checked.filter(".all").length > 0) // ...at least one "All" box is checked...
{
    // remainder of code, including else block, unchanged
}
```

I also added an `all` class to the appropriate `checkbox` elements to simplify the above conditional.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WZpMh/111/)

Comment: It looks great :-D So to add additional data-attributes all I need to do is add them to 'var selected'? Also, you mentioned that it's a mostly working example - what else would I need to do to finish it?

Comment: I discovered one slight hiccup - When I added the links for 'All Colors' & 'All Styles' I discovered that those work when selected but not when unselected (the items all remain visible)

Comment: Also, how would I modify this new function to work with checkboxes? (I tried it but the function stopped running). I added   'input[type="checkbox"]' to the click function, but I wasn't if I needed to modify other portions of the code as well

Comment: @ChayaCooper - I'm glad the answer was helpful and thank you for accepting it. :) Now to your questions....Extra `data-attributes`: if these correspond to additional groups of "choices", then yes, it's simple. Add the "type" to the `selected` variable initialization, `price: []` for example. You'll also need to add the `data-type="price"` attribute to the container for the new choices, and also make sure it has the `filterOptions` class so the existing handler will run. Keep in mind that performance can and will be an issue eventually with each new "type" added.

Comment: Checkboxes: I actually had my initial working example using checkboxes since that's what was there originally (can't find the fiddle though :( ). I ended up switching to match your updated question/fiddle. "Slight hiccup": that's one of the things I noticed that lead to my "mostly working" statement. :) I have an idea what's happening. Do you have an updated fiddle with the "All" buttons that also uses checkboxes? It might be easier to just modify a working sample than to post code fragments here as a comment.

Comment: LOL - I'd actually switched the fiddle because I had discovered that it was buggy and thought it made more sense to post code that was working properly :-) I'll put together the new fiddle now :-D

Comment: Here's a new fiddle with your code + the 'All' buttons and  checkboxes :-) http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/108/ I'm thrilled that you're able to help me with this because the other solutions I found were overly complicated and were a mess to try to integrate with my beautiful new code :-)

Comment: @ChayaCooper - I've updated my answer with the changed parts of the code and linked to the new fiddle. There are probably more efficient ways to tackle this. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a plugin out there to do this as well. In any event, thanks for the interesting challenge. :)

Comment: You're amazing!!! There really isn't a plugin that does this and I'm sure that a lot of people would be thrilled if you turned this into one :-D (I looked for quite some time and the closest I've seen in Filtrify, but it had too many limitations including not being able to combine it with a website's menu)

Comment: I'm sorry that the "All" option turned out to be more complicated than you'd expected, but glad that you had fun with it :-) There's one tiny thing that still needs to be tweaked with it - I'll probably have a 'Show All'/'Remove All Filters' button and would want that to work the way it is now, but for the "All Colors"/"All Styles", etc. buttons it should still apply the filters selected in the other attributes (for example, if "All Colors" is checked but "All Styles" isn't than the 'style' filters should be applied)

Comment: Lol. With all the requirements changes, the release date might slip. :) I've checked some of your other recent questions and it looks like the "show all" functionality may have been taken care of. So release can go on schedule. Lol.

Comment: Lol. I actually haven't fixed that yet ;-) (I didn't want to mess with your code because there was still an issue with the answer I got from A.V)